# I want insert to VAR in the tal:repeat

Tags: php, phptal

I want to know how to use this tal:repeat in my case.
For example, I made this two codes:

```
tr>

  td tal:repeat="table_info table_info" tal:content="table_info/Field"/>

/tr>

tr tal:repeat="select_all select_all">

  1td tal:content="select_all/ (here) "/>

  2td tal:content="select_all/ (here) "/>

  3td tal:content="select_all/ (here) "/>

/tr>
```

If `table_info/Field` has 3 field names(length=3(no, id, pw)), 
how create three `<td>` and insert `no,id,pw` at (here)

Comment: I think your question would benefit from proper formatting and some more, specific information into which concrete programming problem you run with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to read key from `select_all` that is in `table_info`:

If `table_info/Field/id` is `foo`, then it will read `select_all/foo`.